# Zxing Scanner not re - initialize

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode-scanner

I tried to implement Zxing Barcode scanner library, I scanned for the first time it scans perfectly and barcode code got to capture. When tried to scan another barcode, the previously captured barcode image remains same.

And also set close button in a scanner itself, or just share best scanner library

[image: Click here to see screen capture]

Code is given below:

```
        package com.erplogic.handledscanner;

        import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;
        import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;

        public class ScannedDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements 
        AsynchronousResponse , ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
        String lineItemID;

        private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
        private LinearLayout  scanner;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanned_details);
            scanner= findViewById(R.id.scan_recycle);
            // Scanner button
            ImageButton scannerButton = findViewById(R.id.scanner_button);
            scannerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(ScannedDetails.this);
            scanner.addView(scannerView);
            }
         }
         });
        }

        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result result) {
            Toast.makeText(ScannedDetails.this, result.getText(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
                    if (scannerView == null) {
                        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(ScannedDetails.this);
                        scanner.addView(scannerView);
                    }
                    scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
                    scannerView.startCamera(); 
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: this is not `ZXing`. file an issue there: https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/issues